# reactjs edit child state from parent

Tags: reactjs

I have an app with 3 components.
The first is App.jsx
which calls the TodoList component as follows:

```
<TodoList items={this.state.items} loaded={this.state.loaded} />
```

the TodoList component renders multiple TodoListItem components

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
render: function(){
  return (
    <ul>
    {this.renderList()}
    </ul>
  )
},
renderList: function(){
    var children = [];
    for(var key in this.props.items) {
      if(this.props.items[key].text){
        var listItem = this.props.items[key];
        listItem.key = key;
        children.push(
          <TodoListItem item={listItem} key={key} onEdit={this.handleItemEdit} />
        )
      }
    }
    return children;
},
handleItemEdit: function(component){
  console.log(component);
}
});
```

Then in my TodolistItem component im rendering multiple li elements

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    text: this.props.item.text,
    done: this.props.item.done
  }
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <li onClick="this.props.onEdit.bind(null,this)">{this.state.text}</li>
  )
},

});
```

When i click on the li the function handlItemEdit on the parent element function is fired, my question is how i can change the text value of the child element in it's parent's handleItemEdit function?
What im trying to do is when you click on a li open a bootstrap modal with an input field, change its text,save and pass the new props to TodoListItem

Answer (score 0):

In `TodoList` component you should write `getInitialState` and save items from props to state, then in render pass items from state (not from props like you did) to `TodoListItem` component:

```
for(var key in this.state.items) {
  if(this.state.items[key].text){
    var listItem = this.state.items[key];
    listItem.key = key;
    children.push(
      <TodoListItem item={listItem} key={key} onEdit={this.handleItemEdit} />
    )
  }
}
```

If you call `setState` within `handleItemEdit` method, `render()` will see the updated state and will be executed.
In this case all you need to do is change state in your `handleItemEdit` and this will be passed to `TodolistItem` where you should use `props`, not `state` in render, like this:

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <li onClick="this.props.onEdit.bind(null,this.props)">{this.props.text}</li>
  )
},
```

Notice you are passing props onEdit, so you have to chane `handleItemEdit` like this:

```
handleItemEdit: function(itemProps){
   console.log('You clicked: ' + this.props.items[itemProps.key]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Because props in todoList come from a http request i've added 
componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
      this.setState({items:this.props.items});
    }
Now in the handleItemEdit how i can only edit the value of the clicked li?
Can i do it by its key?

Comment: `handleItemEdit` should be actually in TodolistItem component not in TodoList component... this will solve your problem

Comment: you can also read this [article](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), to lern how to handle comunication beetwen components to solve your problem in another way (as you oryginally wanted to)

Comment: Yes if i wanted to edit the TodoListItem from inside its component. My problem is that i want to edit it from the TodoList component because in this component lives the modal that will show the input element in order to edit the TodoListItem

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this will work since I can't test it at the moment ;)

Comment: im getting You clicked: undefined

Comment: check my new answer... you have to pass ListItem component to child and then from inside the child pass it back to handleItemEdit function (at least in ECMAScript 6 it works)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested solution of your problem in ECMAScript 6 syntax. It would be very easy to use this solution in your notation too. Basicaly what you have to do is to pass `this` from parent to child, and then use it when you bind onClick event to parent (so you can have `this` in event handler function) as secound parameter you pass `props` of the child, where `key` prop will point the very cilcked element. Then it is very easy to chane parent's state, this will trigger render on parent, and cascade to render child with the new (changed by user) props.

TodoList.js

```
class TodoList extends Component {
    render (){
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map(function(listItem, key) {
                    return (listItem.text &&
                        <TodoListItem item={listItem} todoList={this} key={key} onEdit={this.handleItemEdit}/>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    };

    handleItemEdit(itemProps){
        console.log('You clicked: ' + this.props.items[itemProps.key].text);
    };
}

export default TodoList;
```

TodoListItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TodoListItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li onClick={this.props.onEdit.bind(this.props.todoList, this.props.item)}>{this.props.item.text}</li>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoListItem;
```

I have tested it and it prints the very text you have clicked in console. This means that oyu have access to this TodoListItem and you can change state of it in TodoList component.